# Intellij: maven clean verify: Failed to execute goal org.jasig.mojo.jspc:jspc-maven-plugin:2.0.2:compile: Failed to compile JSPS

Tags: java, maven, jsp, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

My project POM has following plugins-

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jasig.mojo.jspc</groupId>
                <artifactId>jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.jsp</include>
                        </includes>
                    </sources>
                    <includeInProject>false</includeInProject>
                    <validateXml>false</validateXml>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jasig.mojo.jspc</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jspc-compiler-tomcat8</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>utf8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I'm using apache-maven-3.6.3 and Intellij IDE for building my project.
But when executing mvn clean verify, I get the error-

> Failed to execute goal
> org.jasig.mojo.jspc:jspc-maven-plugin:2.0.2:compile: Failed to compile
> JSPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to in tomcat 7 by default SKIP IDENTIFIER CHECK feature is false.

Hence supply`-Dorg.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true` as an argument while maven clean installing.

Alternatively a work around is also to use org.apache.sling jspc-maven-plugin

```
             <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                <artifactId>jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile-jsp</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jspc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```